# php help. confused with update

Tags: php

I have a two tables, one for student records and one for siblings of the student.

When I  want to update the tables, I echo them to textareas.

I don't have any problems doing this for the student table, but for the siblings table, if the student has two or more siblings, my update fails because the name of the textareas becomes the last row (the last sibling).

How do I deal with this one-to-many relationship?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$database="sy_database"; 
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", ""); 
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
$id=$_GET['up']; 
$sno=$_GET['s_no'];
$order = "SELECT * FROM sy_form WHERE reg_no='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($order); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
?>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "<form method=post action=ambot.php>";
mysql_select_db("sy_database", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sy_form where reg_no='$id'");
echo "<body align=center>";
echo"Student Record";
echo "<table border='1' width=1000px margin=0 padding=0 align=center>
<tr bgcolor=yellow>
<th>Reg No.</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date of Birth</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Class</th>
<th>School</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr align=center>";
echo "<td><textarea readonly=readonly rows=1 cols=3 name=reg_no>". $row['reg_no'] ."                    </textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=20 name=name>" .$row['name']. "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=20 name=birth>" . $row['birth'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=3 name=age>" . $row['age'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=3 name=sclass>" . $row['sclass'] . "</textarea>     </td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=20 name=school>" . $row['school'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sy_form where reg_no='$id'");
echo "<br><table border='1' width=1250px margin=0 padding=0 align=center>
<tr bgcolor=yellow>
<th>Father's Name</th>
<th>Father's Occupation</th>
<th>Mother's Name</th>
<th>Mother's Occupation</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Phone No.</th>
<th>Cellphone No.</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr align=center>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=20 name=fname>" . $row['fname'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=10 name=focc>" . $row['focc'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=20 name=mname>" . $row['mname'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=10 name=mocc>" . $row['mocc'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=25 name=address>" . $row['address'] . "</textarea>        </td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=8 name=phone>" . $row['phone'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=10 name=cp>" . $row['cp'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=20 name=email>" . $row['email'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

echo"<br/>Student's Sibling(s)";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siblings where reg_no='$id' AND s_no<min($sno)");

echo "<br/><table border='1' margin=0 padding=0 align=center>
<tr bgcolor=yellow>
<th>Reg No.</th>
<th>Sibling No.</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>School</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr align=center>";
  echo "<td align=right><textarea readonly=readonly rows=1 cols=3 name=reg_no>".     $row['reg_no'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=3>" . $row['s_no'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 name=sname>" . $row['sname'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=3 name=sage>" . $row['sage'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "<td><textarea rows=1 name=sschool>" . $row['sschool'] . "</textarea></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type =submit value =update />";
echo "</form>";
mysql_close($con);
?>

<?php
$database="sy_database"; 
$id=$_POST['id']; 
$ip=$_POST['ip']; 
$mac=$_POST['mac']; 
$location=$_POST['location']; 
$use=$_POST['use']; 
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", ""); 
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
$order = "UPDATE sy_form 
SET name='$name' WHERE reg_no='$reg_no'"; 
$result=mysql_query($order); 

if($result){ 
echo "<p style=margin-top:50px;><BR><BR><BR></p>"; 
echo "<a href='view.php'>Back to Records</a>"; 
} 

else { 
echo "ERROR"; 
echo $name; 
} 
?>
```

here's my update code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("sy_database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE  sy_form SET name='$name', birth='$birth', age='$age',         sclass='$sclass',  school='$school' , fname='$fname', focc='$focc', mname='$mname',     mocc='$mocc', address='$address', phone='$phone', cp='$cp', email='$email' where reg_no='$reg'");

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE  siblings SET sname='$sname',sage='$sage', sschool='$sschool' where reg_no='$reg'");
echo("record updated.");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

HERE's my html code for the INSERT:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type = "text/css">
            body {
            font-family: Arial;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
            table{
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #masterdiv {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #header {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 796px;
            height: 10;
            background-image: url('header.jpg');
            }
            #fillForm {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            #footer {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 798px;
            height: 75px;
            background-image: url('footer.jpg');
            }
        </style>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="black">

        <div id = "masterdiv">
            <div id = "header"></div>
            <div id = "fillForm">
            <p align="right" style="color:red;font-size:60px;"/> Registration Form</p>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

                <form action = "cc.php" method ="post">
                        <tr bgcolor="red">
                        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>

                        <td><b>Registration No:</b></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" name = "reg_no"></td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name: </td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "40" name = "name"></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Date of Birth: </td>
                        <td><input type = "text" name = "birth"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age: </td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "20" name = "age"></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Class as at January: </td>
                        <td><input type = "text" name = "sclass"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>School: </td>
                        <td colspan = "4"><input type = "text" size = "80" name = "school"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Father's Name: </td>
                        <td colspan = "4"><input type = "text" size = "80" name = "fname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Father's Occupation: </td>
                        <td colspan = "4"><input type = "text" size = "80" name = "focc"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mother's Name: </td>
                        <td colspan = "4"><input type = "text" size = "80" name = "mname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mother's Occupation: </td>
                        <td colspan = "4"><input type = "text" size = "80" name = "mocc"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "5">Siblings (if any)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>School</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1. <input type = "text" size = "50" name = "sname"></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "25" name = "sage"></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "30" name = "sschool"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2. <input type = "text" size = "50" name = "sname2"></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "25" name = "sage2"></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "30" name = "sschool2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3. <input type = "text" size = "50" name = "sname3"></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "25" name = "sage3"></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" size = "30" name = "sschool3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align = "right">
                        <td colspan = "3">Address: <input type = "text" size = "80" name = "address"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align = "right">
                        <td colspan = "3">Phone Number: <input type = "text" size = "80" name = "phone"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align = "right">
                        <td colspan = "3">Cellphone Number (Mother/Father)<input type = "text" size = "80" name = "cp"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align = "right">
                        <td colspan = "3">Email: <input type = "text" size = "80" name = "email"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr align = "center">
                        <td colspan = "3">
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name = "Submit">

                        </form>


                        <form action="view.php" method="post" target="_blank">  
                        <input type = "submit" value = "View/Update/Delete" name = "View" >
                        </form>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div id = "footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's the PHP code for INSERT:

```
<?php   

    //student record details
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $birth = $_POST['birth'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $sclass = $_POST['sclass'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $focc = $_POST['focc'];
    $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    $mocc = $_POST['mocc'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $cp = $_POST['cp'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $reg = $_POST['reg_no'];

    //siblings record
    $sname = $_POST['sname'];
    $sage = $_POST['sage'];
    $sschool = $_POST['sschool'];

    $sname2 = $_POST['sname2'];
    $sage2 = $_POST['sage2'];
    $sschool2 = $_POST['sschool2'];

    $sname3 = $_POST['sname3'];
    $sage3 = $_POST['sage3'];
    $sschool3 = $_POST['sschool3'];

    // connect to mysql
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
            or die("ERR: Connection");

    // connect to database        
    $db = mysql_select_db("sy_database", $conn)
          or die("ERR: Database");



    // create mysql query
    // Insert a row of information into the table "sy_form"
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sy_form (reg_no, name, birth, age, sclass, school, fname, focc, mname, mocc, address, phone, cp, email)
    VALUES('".$reg."', '".$name."', '".$birth."', '".$age."', '".$sclass."', '".$school."', '".$fname."', '".$focc."', '".$mname."', '".$mocc."','".$address."','".$phone."','".$cp."','".$email."')";  
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }

echo "1 record added";
    // execute query
    $exec = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 

    // Insert a row of information into the table "sy_form" (1st sibling)
    $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO siblings (reg_no,s_no, sname, sage, sschool)
    VALUES('".$reg."','', '".$sname."', '".$sage."', '".$sschool."')";   
        if($sname==null)
        return 0;

        else
        $exec = mysql_query($sql_1, $conn);      

    // Insert a row of information into the table "sy_form" (2nd sibling)
      $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO siblings (reg_no,s_no, sname, sage, sschool)
    VALUES('".$reg."','', '".$sname2."', '".$sage2."', '".$sschool2."')";
        if($sname2==null)
        return 0;

        else
        $exec = mysql_query($sql_2, $conn);
    // Insert a row of information into the table "sy_form" (3rd sibling)       
    $sql_3 = "INSERT INTO siblings (reg_no,s_no, sname, sage, sschool)
    VALUES('".$reg."','', '".$sname3."', '".$sage3."', '".$sschool3."')";
        if($sname3==null)
        return 0;

        else
        $exec = mysql_query($sql_3, $conn);


        echo ("The following data has been added to sy_database");
?>
```

Comment: That's a [*data modeling problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_modeling), not a PHP problem. You're trying to capture a record of a (specific kind of) relationship, so you need to properly conceptualize and model your domain, and then describe that model in your database structure. Then code up your solution. Or, let [ORM methodologies](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) extract it from you.

Comment: Also, there's [PHP Academy](http://phpacademy.org/) and [](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) (the latter not offering PHP, but plenty of Javascript and HTML tutorials, as well as Ruby).

Comment: It sounds like his modeling is all figured out, he just didn't know how to do post arrays. Although that part of it definitely isn't that clear.

Comment: @aron.duby - I don't know, it sounds like his model is not very "robust" according to the description (ie, one field in another table for "sibling"). Maybe that's the case. What do I know.

Comment: well, it's not really a PHP problem. it's my problem, actually. I know I'm an ignorant. since this is my first time. and no one has taught me anything about this. and it happened that my professor demanded us to make this. so please, could anyone point out what my problem is? and how could I solve it? someone said I DON'T KNOW HOW TO POST ARRAYS, and I admit that's right. can anyone teach me how?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can add [] to the end of the field name to have it post as an array. You didn't post any of the update code, so here's a quick general example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="sibling[unique_id][reg_no]" />
<input type="text" name="sibling[unique_id][name]" />
<input type="text" name="sibling[unique_id][birth]" />
... and so on
```

PHP:

```
// connect to your database as normal
// do your student update as normal

// now we're looping through siblings
foreach($_POST['sibling'] AS $sibling){
    $reg_no = $sibling['reg_no'];
    $name = $sibling['name'];
    $birth = $sibling['birth'];
    ... and so on to set all your variables

    // and now you can run your update query
}
```

If the siblings have their own unique id you can specify that in the brackets, so `name="sibling[unique_id]"` and then in php you would have `$_POST['sibling']['unique_id']`

Comment: hmm.. alright. I'm still confused, somehow. I'm gonna try this. :D

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("sy_database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE  sy_form SET name='$name', birth='$birth', age='$age', sclass='$sclass',  school='$school' , fname='$fname', focc='$focc', mname='$mname', mocc='$mocc', address='$address', phone='$phone', cp='$cp', email='$email' where reg_no='$reg'");

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE  siblings SET sname='$sname',sage='$sage', sschool='$sschool' where reg_no='$reg'");
echo("record updated.");
mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: I've updated my answer to use code that's closer to your actual code. Just keep in mind that since you're not escaping any thing this is a big hole for sql injection. that could be fixed by change `$birth = $sibling['birth'];` to `$birth = mysql_real_escape_string($sibling['birth']);` but I won't get to much into that here since it's not the question

Comment: ei Aron. the primary key of the siblings table is the s_no (sibling no) while the foreign key is the reg_no. I'm still confused. :(
I have no Problems with the INSERT. My only problem now is how to UPDATE it. yes, I can easily retrieve the data from the database to be shown on the browser. but I can't UPDATE the siblings table. T_T

Comment: since i've put it in a WHILE loop. therefore, there could only be one name for each field. for example, if there are 2 siblings, and I've set the name of the textarea to be "sname" the 2nd sibling would just be the only one to carry that text area name.and when i edit it, let say a 2nd sibling who has a name "Ruby" and then I changed it to "Diamond" the 1st first sibling would also have the name Diamond. Do you have any idea how to name a textarea differently in a while loop, like incrementing? ---------------------*this is so embarrassing*